# Query a list on site A from subsite B via SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer-workflow, app-step

I have a Designer 2013 Workflow on a subsite (B) that needs to query a calendar on its parent site (A), to see if there is a matching entry in the calendar. If there is no matching entry, I want to create an item on that calendar.

My workflow queries the calendar on A via a REST call to a web service.

When I run my workflow, I get "Forbidden" in the responseCode. I got this before wrapping the code in an App Step, and I am still getting it after configuring both the parent site and the subsite to allow workflows to run using app steps, and adding an app step to my workflow. What am I missing here?

PS- I can confirm that the url to the web service I'm calling works - if I copy it out of the app step and paste it into my browser, I get the results I expect to get from the query.

Comment: Remove the Authorization from your dictionary and try it

Comment: I was still getting zero results when trying it without the App Step.

Comment: App step is needed for this operation.

Comment: I do have an app step, and I still get "Forbidden".

Comment: before the rest call in your workflow, you would have built a dictionary, in that remove Authorization  and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction. The actual solution is that I had to add the app permissions from Subsite A to Site B's app permissions, not just enable app permissions on each site.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the REST call that works fine in the browser, it lists all the
>   available items in the list
>
> The browser is using the authentication cookies from the browser, so
>   it is working with your credentials. The workflow is by default using
>   a service account.
>
> You say you have added an App step. Did you go to the other site and
>   configure app permissions? Did you use this URL as part of the
>   process? http://{hostname}/{the Site
>   Collection}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
>
> See this article for details on setting up the app permissions:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

**This [link](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/) has a working solution for your issue, try it.**

Comment: I have enabled App permissions on both A and B. Yes, I used the /appinv.aspx page to configure the app permissions.